# Show that there exist a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space and let $0\lt k\lt n$. If $K$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of $V$ and $I$ is an $n-k$ dimensional subspace of $V$, show that there exist a linear operator $f: V \to V$ such that $\ker f = K$ and $\Im{f} = I$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: MathJax tip: `\Im`, which renders as $\Im$, is really designed for the imaginary part of complex numbers (there's also a corresponding `\Re`, though I find that nobody really likes using them). If you want to use custom maths operators like $\ker$, use the `\operatorname{}` command. For example, `\operatorname{Im} f = I` renders as $\operatorname{Im} f = I$.